# Handlebars: Organizing and accessing remote templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I want to organize my HB template in different HTML files. So, I have `helpers.html` which contains `<script id='alert' type='text/template>...</script>` and `<script id='notification' type='text/template'></script>`, so how would I access the particular template in this file?
With Jquery we would do something like this `$('#alert')`, but this is a remote template... Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea: try to use them, if you don't find what you're looking for, load it.

This is a simple example, but you can be smarter with more sophisticated solutions:

```
function useAlert(){
  var el = $('#alert');
  // in case el is available carry on
  if(el){
    // do whatever you want
  } else {
    // here we're loading the templates inside an element with id #templates'
    // in the callback we're using the recursion to call again this method
    $('#templates').load('/path/to/helpers.htm', function(error){
      // debug... remove the console log in production
      if(error){
        return console.log('Error', error);
      }
      // try again now
      useAlert();
    });
  }
```